# (event: MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>) => void' is not assignable to type '() => Event'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

It seems pretty simple but I can't handle this problem
I always get same message in console:

> **Type error:** Type '(event: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '() => Event'.  TS2322

This is my code:

```
//in one class  
//some code 
render() 
    return (
        <div className={keyStyle} key={key} onClick={() => this.props.turnKey()}></div>
    )

//in other classs
//some code
    return (
       <div className="container">
          <Display />
          <Keys turnKey={this.activateKey}/>
       </div>
    );
  }

  activateKey = (event : React.MouseEvent): void =>{
      console.log(event.target);
  }
```

**How do I solve this error?**

Comment: Could you clarify which component is including which component?

Answer (score 10):

You did not pass `event` (which is necessary) to your `this.props.turnKey`.
I recommend you to pass `this.props.turnKey` as is:

```
<div className={keyStyle} key={key} onClick={this.props.turnKey}>
```

Probably, it should solve your problem.

---

If not, then there is some problem with declaration of the prop `this.props.turnKey`. Possibly, you have declared it like this

```
turnKey: () => Event
```

instead of

```
turnKey: (event: React.MouseEvent) => void
```

Comment: i did it then i remove parameters from activateKey()  function but i have new problem now with event.target :
TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
I tried with if(event.target !== undefined)... still not work

Answer (score 0):

About the problem with event.target : TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

You could declare the target as HTMLDivElement.
Thus

```
  activateKey = (event : React.MouseEvent): void =>{
    const clickedElement = event.target as HTMLDivElement;
    console.log(clickedElement.value); // ot whatever you need
  }
```

should do the trick.